# two tape Turing machine that accepts L = {ww | w belongs to {0,1}*} in Linear time

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

> Describe a Turing Machine with two tapes that accepts $$L = \{ww \mid w \in \{0,1\}^*\} $$ in a linear time complexity. The input will be on Tape $\#1$ and the marker will point to the first element of the tape.

basically my idea was to copy the first string to the other
going to the middle in the first tape, going to the start in the second tape
and comparing the 1st half of the word with the second.
but the problem is that there is no STAY operation for the marker, only Left or Right.

much appreciated.

Comment: For any TM that can go left, right or not move and runs in time $T(n)$, you can build another TM that always goes either right or left and runs in time $O(T(n))$. For one tape, it's easy: when you want to stay, just do right and then left. For two tapes, it gets harder because doing that means that you will always have an even distances between the two heads. To fix this, you can replace tapes by tapes where you only write to slots of even index. And then, replacing right by two rights, left by two lefts, and stay by right left works.

Comment: I got ya, this answered my question.
kept the 0.5 ratio by using 4:2 instead 2:1.